# How to update ManyToMany "self" in Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, i have a model that looks like this.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    similar = models.ManyToManyField("self", null=True, blank=True)
```

When this model is serialized it returns a list of int's.  I simply need to append to that list of int's inside my serializer.  For some reason the solution escapes me.

My serializer's update method where I need to append to the list looks like this.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.similar = validated_data.get('similar', instance.similar)
```

What this does, is it will save the new int I pass in just fine, **but will not append to what is already there**.  This is what I need to figure out.

My thanks to anybody that can assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *theory*, that does the job:

```
# Disclaimer: anti-pattern
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    added = validated_data.get('similar', None)
    if added:
        instance.similar.add(*added)
    return instance
```

The problem with this kind of logic is, that it is now no longer possible to remove items from the `manytomany` relation with the `PUT` request.

This is the reason why in most cases it is better to **send all** `IDs` that should be preserved with each `PUT` request.

Comment: thank you, for some reason, the data is not sent to the serializer if I don't pass a single int the serializer returns an empty list.  If I pass in a single int, it will update the many to many for that one field.  passing a list of values returns nothing?

Comment: I'm not sure what the star is in there, is that a typo?  Either way your solution is correct.  I can simply extract the value that needs to be added without overwriting what's there and then simply add.  As far as the problem of removing items, I suppose it is an anti-pattern.  I would guess I could create an additional serializer that called for removing these items from the many to many in an opposite way?  Might seem a bit hackish but I think that would suffice.

Comment: The `*` is necessary because `validated_data.get('similar')` returns a list of instances. E.g. if you used the request to `PUT` not only one, but several related objects, it would contain many instances of `MyModel` in this list. The [`add()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) method can process multiple items at once, but it expects each item to be passed as a parameter rather than a list. This is what the `*` does, it unpacks all items in the list and maps them to separate parameters in a function or method call.